# Can I launch rqt_console from a .launch file?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for convenience as I am deep into debugging and am constantly doing a multi step launch procedure. I looked through the wiki and googled, but cannot find a reference to it. Maybe its not possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315772/can-i-launch-rqt_console-from-a-.launch-file?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to add the following to one of your included launch files:

```
<node pkg="rqt_console" type="rqt_console" name="rqt_console"/>
```

The name field is arbitrary.

I don't use `rqt_console` but if there are arguments you are adding during your multi step launch procedure you can further customize by doing:

```
<node pkg="rqt_console" type="rqt_console" name="rqt_console" args="[custom commands]"/>
```

I do that with `rqt_reconfigure` sometimes. For example, if I start a node and name it `my_node` and `my_node` has a dynamic reconfigure server, then I can do:

```
<node pkg="rqt_reconfigure" type="rqt_reconfigure" name="my_rqt_reconfigure" args="my_node"/>
```

That causes an `rqt_reconfigure` GUI to open and it will pre-select `my_node` for me.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2019-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2